# Media play/pause toggling without using too many if statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, howler.js

I am creating a playlist of songs for a website that looks like this:
[image]

However, I am struggling to figure out the proper way to implement all of the possible case statements that a user may go through while toggling the buttons such as:

- toggling one play button on and off
- toggling one play button on, and then clicking another play button so that the previous has to toggle off
- and so on.

Right now my code (below) works for every case EXCEPT for when a user toggles a play button on and off, and then clicks a different play button. This specific case causes both of the icons to toggle to the pause button instead of just the most recently clicked. I know why this happens, it is because an ID of `lastPlayed` is left on the old play button, thus triggering the toggle `if` statment.

My question is, is there an easier way to set up play button toggling that covers all of these cases without having to make a specific `if` statement for every possible outcome?

Either finding a better solution or fixing my one bug works, but cleaner code is always preferred, thanks for any help!

```
var playCounter = 0;

function clickSongPlay(artist, title, url, imageURL, element) {

    //debugger;
    player.playlist.push(
        {
            title: title,
            artist: artist,
            file: url,
            imageURL: imageURL,
            howl: null
        }
    );

    //check to see if we need to resume the song
    if ($(element).hasClass("resumeSong") && $(".music-control").hasClass("ion-ios-play")) {
        console.log("resuming");
        /////////LINE BELOW RESUMES THE TRACK FROM CURRENT POSITION////////
        player.play();
        $(element).toggleClass("ion-ios-play ion-ios-pause");
        $(".resumeSong").removeClass("resumeSong");
        return;
    }

    //if a song is playing and the pause button is clicked, pause the track
    if ($(element).hasClass("ion-ios-pause")) {
        console.log("pausing");
        player.pause();
        $(element).toggleClass("ion-ios-pause ion-ios-play");
        $(element).addClass("resumeSong");
        return;
    }

    //start playing a new song
    if ($(element).hasClass("ion-ios-play") && !$(element).hasClass("resumeSong")) {

        if ($("#lastPlayed") && !playCounter == 0) {
            console.log("here is a new song");
            $("#lastPlayed").toggleClass("ion-ios-pause ion-ios-play")
            $(".music-control").removeAttr("id", "lastPlayed");
        }

        console.log("new song");
        ///////LINE BELOW LOADS THE NEW SONG//////////////
        player.skipTo(player.playlist.length - 1);
        $(element).toggleClass("ion-ios-play ion-ios-pause");
        $(element).attr("id", "lastPlayed");
        playCounter += 1;
        return;
    }

}
```

Here is the HTML for a specific song div:

```
<div><i class="icon ion-ios-play music-control" onclick="clickSongPlay('@song.Artist','@song.Title','@song.URL','@song.Album.ImageURL', this);"></i></div>
```

Comment: How the play buttons are designated as such? I.e. is `.music-control` a CSS class, applied to all the play buttons?

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev See the HTML line I added? Every single song item (shown in the top image) has those classes. When a play button is clicked, the `ion-ios-play` class is toggled to `ion-ios-pause` those are css classes from the Ionicons library. `.music-control` is on every class for every song. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I can see it, there are two problems here.

One, you need to pause any song that is currently playing, whenever an `element` is clicked. The step that is missing from your code is the position at which we the playing song is advanced so far. I'd record this into a `data-offset` property of the element itself. So later, we can continue playback from where it left...

Two, find out if the clicked element is on pause or not. If it is - resume, else play from the beginning.

So here is UNTESTED code sample, which might set you on the right track:

```
function clickSongPlay(artist, title, url, imageURL, element) {
    var nowPlaying = $(element).siblings(".ion-ios-pause")
    if (nowPlaying) {
        player.pause();
        nowPlaying.data("offset") = player.seek();
        nowPlaying.toggleClass("ion-ios-pause ion-ios-play");
        nowPlaying.addClass("resumeSong");
    }

    player.src(url);
    player.seek($(element).data("offset"));

    if ($(element).hasClass("resumeSong")) {
        console.log("resuming");

        $(element).removeData("offset");
        $(element).toggleClass("ion-ios-play ion-ios-pause");
        $(element).removeClass("resumeSong");
    }

    player.play();
}
```

Comment: just running this snippet, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of null` which doesn't make sense because I defined this js script at the very bottom of the file, so it should be defined?

Comment: The `player` variable should be initialized before the execution enters the `clickSongPlay` function.

Comment: just checked, looks like `player` is defined just above the `clickSongPlay` I can send my js file? What would be the best way to send that